# Slick2d/lwjgl Curve through Array of Points

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I am trying to rewrite the Game "Achtung, die Kurve" (Attention, the Curve)

Now, i am stuck with the Problem:
How can i draw a Curve, which goes through N Points(x/y Coords)

```
for(int i = 0;i < xList.size();i++)
    {
        path.lineTo(player1.getShape().getCenterX(),player1.getShape().getCenterY());
    }
```

^This will always create a new Line, so my FPS get to 10 very quickly

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

This is an algebra problem that can be solved with systems of linear equations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Generally, a curve that passes through N points is an (N-1)th degree polynomial. So if you want to find a polynomial that passes through 3 points (e.g. `(-1,1), (0, 3), (1, -1)`) you would need a quadratic equation like this: `ax^2+bx+c=y`.

To find the values of a,b, and c, you need the plug the x and y coordinates in, then solve the system of equations.

> a(-1)^2+b(-1)+c=1 
>   a(0)^2+b(0)+c=3
>   a(1)^2+b(1)+c=-1

that simplifiles to

> a-b+c=1
>   c=3
>   a+b+c=-1

Nicely, we already have *c=3*. By combining the first equation and the second we can get

> 2a+2c=0

Since we know c=3, this becomes

> 2a+3=0

So `a=-1.5`.

From here we can put these values of a and c into the last equation to get this

> -1.5+b+3=-1

Which gives a `b=-3.5`. Plugging these values of a,b, and c back into the quadratic equation yields this

> -1.5x^2-3.5x+3=y

I haven't double checked my math, but if I did it correctly, this will give a quadratic curve that passes through the three points.

Undoubtedly, there is already a library out there for doing this, but I'm sorry to say I don't know what that would be. Hopefully, knowing about the math behind your problem will help you find your answer.